# CodeIgniter: Populate an input text in the view from data array grabbed from database

Tags: php, codeigniter

This return of print_r($query->result()); would be:

**Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [guest_name] => Test Name [guest_gender] => Male [guest_nic_pp_dl] => 123456789 ) )**

What I need is to pass those values into input text boxes, radio buttons and dropdowns in the view respectilvely.

For example, I need 'guest_name' to be in an input, 'guest_gender' value to be selected on the view, and dropdown value corresponding to 'guest_nic_pp_dl' to be selected on a dropdown (HTML select).

**Controller:**

```
function get_customer_details() {
    $guest_name = $this->input->post('guest_name');
    $this->banquet_model->talk_to_new_guest_table($guest_name);
    $this->load->view('/main/banquet_view');
}
```

**Model:**

```
function talk_to_new_guest_table($guest_name) {
    $query = $this->db->query(" SELECT guest_name, guest_gender, guest_nic_pp_dl
                                FROM new_guest 
                                WHERE guest_name LIKE '$guest_name%'
                                LIMIT 1 ");
    if($query->num_rows()>0) {
        return $query->result();
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<div class="control-group">   
<label for="guest_name" class="control-label"><i class="icon-user"></i> Name: </label>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-append">
        <input type="text" id="appendedInputButtons" class="span2" name="guest_name" value="<?php echo set_value('guest_name'); ?>">
        <input class="btn" type="submit" name="searchGuest" value="Search">
    </div>
<?php echo form_error('guest_name'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Where are you returning the result?

Comment: I haven't yet. I tried to echo in the view but it didn't work. I need to populate simple text boxes and they are not shown in the above code. For example, <input type="text" id="appendedInputButtons" class="span2" name="sth" >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers from  Rajeev Ranjan and Prasanth are ok but on the line `return $query->result();` you can do this`return $query->row();` the reason is because the result() returns an array of objects which needs to be iterated while the row() object returns a single object which you can reference without iterating with a loop. I hope this will help

Answer (score 2):

make some changes in

Controller :

```
$guest=$this->banquet_model->talk_to_new_guest_table($guest_name);
 //creating data array from returned result
 $data['guest_name']=$guest->guest_name;
 $data['guest_gender']=$guest->guest_gender;
 $data['guest_nic_pp_dl']=$guest->guest_nic_pp_dl;
 //loading view with data
 $this->load->view('/main/banquet_view',$data);
```

more important all these data array  element will be available as variable on view page like

```
$data['guest_gender'] as $guest_gender
```

Comment: Oh, wait... Now it returns 3 "Trying to get property of non-object" messages

Comment: @saucecord on where ?
are you using like this 
 <input type="text" id="appendedInputButtons" class="span2" name="guest_name" value="<?php echo $guest_name ?>">

Comment: @saucecord what is returning 3 and where you are getting "Trying to get property of non-object"...

Comment: As soon as I submit, it returns backs to index(); (...which I expected) and gives the error.

Comment: Not returning 3. I meant to say 3 error messages. "trying to get property of non object"

Comment: @saucecord cant help with this info .it is possible that result is returning nothing .

Answer (score 1):

Try something on the lines of:

Controller:

```
function get_customer_details() {
    $guest_name = $this->input->post('guest_name');
    $data = $this->banquet_model->talk_to_new_guest_table($guest_name);
    if ($data != 0) {
        $this->load->view('/main/banquet_view', $data);
    }
}
```

Model:

```
function talk_to_new_guest_table($guest_name) {
    $query = $this->db->query(" SELECT guest_name, guest_gender, guest_nic_pp_dl
                                FROM new_guest 
                                WHERE guest_name LIKE '$guest_name%'
                                LIMIT 1 ");
    if($query->num_rows()>0) {
        return $query->result();
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

View:

```
<div class="control-group">   
<label for="guest_name" class="control-label"><i class="icon-user"></i> Name: </label>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-append">
        <input type="text" id="appendedInputButtons" class="span2" name="guest_name" value="<?php echo $guest_name; ?>">
        <input class="btn" type="submit" name="searchGuest" value="Search">
    </div>
<?php echo form_error('guest_name'); ?>
</div>
```